# How to make a blinking "cursor/rectangle" in CSS after "normal" text?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

What I am trying to do is make that purple square blink every second right after "MY NAME HERE". (Similar to the cursor if you open up the Terminal) [Here is a screenshot of what it looks like right now in a browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqBFo.png)

```css
.intro-container {
     margin: 0 auto;
     margin-top: 20vh;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     justify-content: flex-end;
}

.intro-title::before {
      content: ">\A0"
}

.intro-container .intro-title {
}

.blinking {
     width: 50px;
     height: 100px;
     background-color: rgba(116,127,224,.65);
     animation-name: blob;
     animation-duration: 1s;
     animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes blinking {
    50% {
        background-color: transparent
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="intro-container">
    <div class="intro-title">
        MY NAME HERE <div class="blinking"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that your `animation-name` is not set to the correct value. Change it to `blinking` (the name of your keyframes) instead of `blob` so that it uses that animation that you set up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.blinking {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgba(116,127,224,.65);
    -webkit-animation: blinking 2s infinite;
    animation: blinking 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes blinking {
    0% {
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    49% {
        background-color: transparent
    }
    50% {
        background-color: rgba(116,127,224,.65);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! it is blinking but not on the same line. I changed '-webkit-animation:' and 'animation:' to 1s but that was a personal tweak.

Comment: adding display: inline-block; and vertical-align: middle; to .blinking might be what you're after!